# Get subclass of document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, php, html, subclass, getelementsbyclassname

So, I have this html code:

```
<div class='class1' id='example'>
  <span class='class2'>Some text</span>
  <span class='class3'>Some text 2</span>
 </div>
```

I want to get every class1 and then add an event listener (click) on class2 and class3 (and I need that id to get some info from a PHP file). I tried something like this:

```
var yes = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
for (var i=0 ; i<yes.length;i++)
  yes[i].getElementsByClassName('class2').addEventListener('click',redirectfunction,false);
```

It's not working. What can I do?!

Comment: `yes.lenght`? Perhaps *length*? Also, [*getElementsByClassName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) returns a [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), not a single element, so you can't call *addEventListener* on it.

Comment: You have mis-spelt lenght, getsElementsByClassName and have a dot rather than a comma in the listener.

Comment: is the length typo in your example just a typo in this question?

Comment: It's just a typo, that's not the problem.

Comment: So, to clarify your question: do you have groups of 3 elements such that within each group you need to add the eventListener  'redirectfunction' to the class2 element within that group?

Comment: Yes, that's right... I need to add eventListener 'redirectfunction' on class2 and 'redirectfunction2' on class 3 (and in everyone of these functions I need that id from class1).

Comment: PS: And that id is php generated.

Comment: I never understand why people don't actually post their *real* code instead of typing it back in (with typos)

Comment: I did that because my real code is more complex... and I made a simplified example (with the same structure).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably better to use *querySelectorAll* as it has wider support than *getElementsByClassName* (IE 8+) and you can get the elements in one go:

```
var yes = document.querySelectorAll('.class1 > .class2, .class1 > .class3');
```

*querySelectorAll* returns a static NodeList, so iterate over the returned object to access the members.

However, be prepared to provide a fallback for older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

At first `getsElementsByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` (if not a typo) and then `yes[i].getElementsByClassName('class2')` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements and you are using this:

```
yes[i].getElementsByClassName('class2')
      .addEventListener('click',redirectfunction,false);
```

So, you are trying to add an event listener on a collection. You may use another loop if there are multiple elements or just use something like this:

```
yes[i].getElementsByClassName('class2')[0]
      .addEventListener('click',redirectfunction,false);
```

**Update:** ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq9z2/4/))

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('div.class1');
for(var i =0, l=els.length; i<l; i++) {
    var cls = els[i].querySelectorAll('span[class^=class]');
    for(var x =0, n=cls.length; x<n; x++) {
        cls[x].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            redirectfunction.call(this, e, this.parentNode.id);
        }, false);
    }
}

function redirectfunction(e, id) {
    alert('This is id: ' + id);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. After doing this, how can I get that id from class1 to use it in redirectfunction? When I had only class1, I used e.target.id, but now?

Comment: You can use `addEventListener('click', function(e){redirectfunction.call(this, e, this.id)},false);` then `function redirectfunction(event, id) { /* this is the element that called the listener */}`.

Comment: WereWolf - The Alpha I've tried function redirectfunction(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var id = target.id; // id

} and it doesn't work... RobG, using your code doesn't work, neither (or I don't know how to use it :-o). How can I make an alert, for example, with the id using that code?

Comment: Use `alert('The id is: ' + id);` after you get the `var id`.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't use the same structure... the id is on class1 and the function is used on class2. And I need the id from class1 on the function used in the event listener on class2.

Comment: Check the updated answer, you should have told everything clearly but maybe you said and I missed.

Comment: Now it works. Thank you. I have a little question. When do we use this: function(e) {
            redirectfunction.call(this, e, this.parentNode.id);
        } ? When we need to send an argument? So, it is not possible to do something like function(e, this.parentNode.id)? Am I right? And what is "this" in this particular case?

Comment: Glad it helped you. The question you asked is a broad question, can't answer here, you need to read books or article online. All the best :-)